# How to disable admin login from front end?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, intersection

I'm trying to disable admin login from front end of my wordPress site but my backend login also gets disable both login shows admin cannot login here

```php
<?php

add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_admin_prevent_authentication', 30, 3 );
function wp_admin_prevent_authentication( $user, $username, $password ) {
  if ( $user instanceof WP_User && is_page( 'my-account' ) )  {
    if ( array_intersect( (array) $user->roles, [ 'administrator' ] ) ) {
      return new WP_Error( 'admin-error', 'Admins cannot login from here.' );
    };
  };
  return $user;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you can use `is_page()` inside `authenticate` but you can get page name using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. check the below code.

```
function wp_admin_prevent_authentication( $user, $username, $password ) {
    
    $url = explode( '/', rtrim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') );

    // If in My account dashboard page
    if(  $user instanceof WP_User && end( $url ) == 'my-account' ){ 
        if ( array_intersect( (array) $user->roles, [ 'administrator' ] ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'admin-error', 'Admins cannot login from here.' );
        }
    }

    return $user;
} 
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_admin_prevent_authentication', 30, 3 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

Comment: @Rishek Narayan does my answer help?

Comment: Hi Bhautik Thanks a lot bro it works:) Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code, maybe it will work for you.

```
function wpum_admin_prevent_authentication( $user, $username, $password ) {

    if ( $user instanceof WP_User && is_page( wpum_get_core_page_id( 'login' ) ) ) {
        if ( array_intersect( (array) $user->roles, [ 'administrator' ] ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'admin-error', 'Admins cannot login from here.' );
        }
    }

    return $user;

}
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpum_admin_prevent_authentication', 30, 3 );
```